# Number of times switched in longitudinal data

Tags: r

So, I have a time series with a number of observations per ID. I measure a 1/0 variable at each time point. I want to know how many times a person switches from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1.

There are missing data at random in each ID.

```
id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
indicator=c(1,0,0,0,1,1,NA,1,1,0,1,0,NA,1,1,0)
timepoint=c(2003,2004,2005,2006)
td = data.frame(id,timepoint,indicator)
```

I need code to return the number of switches per person in these data.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number switch from 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 all you need to do is `shifting` your vector and compare the two shifted versions. And they applying this function by id assuming your data is already sorted in chronological order.

```
library(data.table)
count.switch=function(x) sum(tail(x,-1)!= head(x,-1),na.rm=T)
td[,count.switch(indicator),keyby=.(id)]
```

With this method you could specify the switch you would like to count

```
count.switch.01=function(x) sum(tail(x,-1) == 0 & head(x,-1) ==1 ,na.rm=T)
```

You could also count both with a `(==0 & ==1) | (==1 & ==0)`

Another trick would be to count when the shifted vectors add up to 1 element wise. They only do when one element is 0 and the other 1.

```
count.switch=function(x) sum(tail(x,-1) + head(x,-1) == 1,na.rm=T)
```

Comment: td %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(switched = count.switch(indicator)) %>%
  ungroup()